# 301 redirect all urls containing a certain phrase

Tags: redirect

I want to redirect all urls that contain "videoplayer.swf" in them. A load of pages got generated automatically with this and I want to 301 them all to the homepage.

Comment: In what language, php, asp, countless others?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
     if (preg_match ("videoplayer\.swf", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI')) {
         header (...);
         exit;
     }
 ?>
```

Comment: Ah not the htaccess file then!

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you're using apache, here's a .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www\.example\.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*videoplayer\.swf.*$ http://www\.example\.com/ [R,NC]
```

Based on checking the referrer, so you can have something like that viewable, if accessed from your site.

Comment: http://www.ppiclaimsuk.co.uk/blog/how-to-reclaim-ppi/video/bankcharges_videoplayer.swf isn't redirecting using the above htaccess code